Inherit args from the main wp_query or wp_comment_query to my custom query
I want to create a custom wp query but inheriting the args of the main query both for wp_query and the wp_comment_query.
WP QUERY:
$args = array(
 // custom args
)

// Here I need some method to join main query args and my custom args

$my_query = new WP_Query( $args );

WP COMMENT QUERY:
$args = array(
 // custom args
)

// Here I need some method to join main query args and my custom args

$comments_query = new WP_Comment_Query( $args );
$comments = $comments_query->comments;

This because I want to keep all default args and settings (admin settings), I need all default args and I have to set just few custom args keeping default args.
Thanks

is this for a secondary query or to replace the main query? What's the context that requires this functionality? Usually you'd use the pre_get_posts filter to modify the main query rather than creating a new query

@TomJNowell I'm creating a loading posts by ajax using admin-ajax.php, at the moment I used 'query_posts( $args )' to alter main query but it isn't the best way to do it, I tried to use 'pre_get_posts' but it doesn't work, maybe because is it an ajax request? Can you help me to use pre_get_posts using ajax or alter the main query with a new custom query but without losing default query_vars? thanks

query_posts does not alter or modify the main query, it creates a new additional query, there are maybe 1 or 2 acceptable use cases for query_posts that involve standalone PHP files at the top root level of a WP install and are usually related to WordPress core development, as a developer building plugins or themes you should never use it. As for the AJAX request, it's likely that there is't a main query at all, each request loads WP from a blank slate so it has no idea what the main query of the page that had the AJAX js was, it has to be told

@TomJNowell and how do I know all the default query_args that WordPress and the main query uses? I can't point them all out myself, but I have to be able to retrieve them from somewhere.

you can read them using standard APIs such as get_query_var if you know the specific value, though there are other ways. Comments don't have the length of formatting to answer that question though, it'd be best asked as a new question. Fundamentally though a AJAX request could come from anywhere, unless it's told what something is how would it know? Wether that means you want to duplicate the original state as is or if you only care about a subset, or have some other needs though is up to you. It sounds though like this is an X Y problem

@TomJNowell I would just like to make an Ajax call when clicking on pagination and load the next or previous comments, using the native 'wp_list_comment()' functions and 'the_comments_pagination()' that works with global variables...

just comments? If so then WP_Query shouldn't matter as that's for posts not comments, in theory all you need to reproduce the query is which page you want to show, how many comments to show, and for which post. You need to give it that info though, it can't inherit or override the existing values because there aren't any

note though that any answer for this question has to answer the question as it is written, so if your question and your problem don't say the same thing then you need to fix that

don't they say the same thing?  I need it for both comments and posts, as written in my initial question.
